# Testing Try - Catch Django function. Need exception testing

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

it's probably a straightforward simple problem but i haven't found similar information. I want to test a get function, which throws a generic exception, in case any event if the model fails. This is my view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_group(request):
    """
    Returns all works
    """
    try:
        group = Group.objects.all()
        serializer = GroupSerializer(group, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(data={'error': e.args}, status=500)
```

I have the test that does not throw an exception, but I need it to cover the one that throws an exception and I can't find a way. I have tried several things but the closest thing to get right has been this.

```
  def test_get_group_list_fail(self):

        with self.assertRaises(Exception):

            response = self.client.get('/groups/')
            resultados = self.group.objects.all()
            esperado = CrackingGroupSerializer(resultados, many=True)
            self.assertNotEqual(esperado.data, ['fail'])
            assert response.status_code == 500
```

If anyone knows a solution, it is appreciated in advance.

Comment: if you need a generic exception try `except: return HttpResponse(status=500)`

Answer (score 0):

There are mock objects for raising exceptions in code during test (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Try something like this:

```py
@patch('<module_containing_serializers>.CrackingGroupSerializer')
def test_get_group_list_fail(self, MockSerializer):
    MockSerializer.side_effect = Exception()
    response = self.client.get('/groups/')
```

Comment: I've already done this and doesn't work. The status code still returns 200, and i can't get the coverage for the except block of code. Thanks anyway